# Cómo graficar un cubo con 8 cubos internos

Tags: python, plotly, graph

Quiero graficar 8 características de unos panes dentro de un cubo de manera que se represente un cubo mayor y dentro de este 8 cubos más pequeños de diferentes colores.

Cada cubo menor corresponde a la frecuencia de ventas de unos panes en especifico (francés, gallego, acemita, canilla, tiburón, pingüino, turco y escocés). Las tres dimensiones son (color, suavidad, tipo) y toman cada una dos valores: color (blanco, oscuro), suavidad (suave, duro), tipo (normal, integral). Eso da un total de 8 cubos menores dentro del cubo mayor.

Cada cubo debe tener un color unico y se deben dibujar solo los dos cubos con la mayor frecuencia de ventas. Por ejemplo: podría resultar un pan francés (cubo amarillo) dispuesto dentro del cubo mayor en las dimensiones blanco, suave, normal. Y otro cubo podría ser para el pan gallego en las dimensiones oscuro, duro, integral. Las combinaciones dependerán de los resultados.

He diseñado el siguiente código, pero aun no logro graficar con exactitud lo que quiero y los colores no son sólidos:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# breads
breads = ['fre', 'gal', 'ace', 'qui', 'sha', 'pen', 'tur', 'sco']
frecuencies = [1012, 951, 130, 227, 675, 661, 86, 293]

# greater cube
figura_cubo_mayor = go.Mesh3d(
    x=[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],  # Coord x greater cube
    y=[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],  # Coord y greater cube
    z=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # Coord z greater cube
    i=[0, 7, 0, 0, 4, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7],  # index of the faces of the larger cube
    j=[1, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 6],  # index of the faces of the larger cube
    k=[2, 7, 6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 7, 0, 1, 7],  # index of the faces of the larger cube
    intensity=[1],  # color intensity greatest cube
    colorscale='Greys',  
    showscale=False, 
    opacity=0.2  
)

# minor cubes
figuras_cubos_menores = []

for i, frecuencia in enumerate(frecuencias):
    if i >= 8:
        break  # only 8 cubes

    intensidad_color = int(frecuencia * 255)  # color intensity 

    figura_cubo_menor = go.Mesh3d(
        x=[0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0],  # Coord x minor cube
        y=[0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5],  # Coord y minor cube
        z=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1],  # Coord z minor cube
        i=[0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7],  # index of the faces of the minor cube
        j=[1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 6, 7, 1, 4, 2],  # index of the faces of the minor cube
        k=[2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 0, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3, 4],  # index of the faces of the minor cube
        intensity=[intensidad_color],  # conlor Intensity minor cube
        colorscale='Reds',
        showscale=False,
        opacity=1.0 
    )

    figuras_cubos_menores.append(figura_cubo_menor)
# complete figure
figura_completa = go.Figure(data=[figura_cubo_mayor] + figuras_cubos_menores)

# desing of the figure
figura_completa.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(range=[0, 1], tickvals=[0, 0.5]),
        yaxis=dict(range=[0, 1], tickvals=[0, 0.5]),
        zaxis=dict(range=[0, 1], tickvals=[0, 0.5]),
        aspectmode='manual',
        aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=1),
        camera=dict(eye=dict(x=1.25, y=1.25, z=1.25))
    ),
    scene_dragmode=False
)

figura_completa.show()
```

Qué sugerencias me pueden dar que se visualicen dos cubos cualesquiera de mayor frecuencia con sus tres dimensiones.
graficar un cubo con con 8 cubos internos en ploty

Comment: tu codigo da error en la linea `for i, frecuencia in enumerate(frecuencias):`   `NameError: name 'frecuencias' is not defined` Este error esta claro, no has definido la variable `frecuencias`  en lugar de esto tienes una variable `frecuencies` (con e) . simplemente cambia el combre de la variable y solucionado.